# KeyVault GetSecretAsync never returns

Tags: c#, .net, azure, async-await

The sample code for working with KeyVault inside a web application has the following code in it:

```
public static async Task<string> GetSecret(string secretId)
{
    var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(secretId);
    return secret.Value;
}
```

I've incorporated the `KeyVaultAccessor` object included in the sample in my application in order to test it. The call is executed as part of a query to one of my web api controller methods:

```
var secret = KeyVaultAccessor.GetSecret("https://superSecretUri").Result;
```

Unfortunately, the call never returns and the query hangs indefintely...

What might be the reason, because frankly I have no clue where to start...?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the common deadlock issue that I [describe in full on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). In short, the `async` method is attempting to return to the ASP.NET request context after the `await` completes, but that request only allows one thread at a time, and there is already a thread in that context (the one blocked on the call to `Result`). So the task is waiting for the context to be free, and the thread is blocking the context until the task completes: deadlock.

The proper solution is to use `await` instead of `Result`:

```
var secret = await KeyVaultAccessor.GetSecret("https://superSecretUri");
```

Comment: So, if I have an existing application that doesn't use async methods whatsoever, I need to do some refactorings to be able to use this library?

Comment: @GabrielG.Roy: Yes, that is the best approach.

Comment: Is there a quick and dirty approach which will allow me to do these calls synchronously?

Comment: @GabrielG.Roy: No. There are [a variety of hacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx), but none of them work perfectly or in all scenarios.

Comment: I used the other way described in your blog which consists of using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielG.Roy: Just to be clear, that is one of the hacks (not a proper solution), and does not work for all scenarios. It's great if it works for you now, but that particular hack comes with a hefty maintenance burden.

Answer (score 15):

I've used the following code to override the synchronization context:

```
var secret = Task.Run(async () => await KeyVaultAccessor.GetSecretAsync("https://superSecretUri")).Result;
```

This still lets you use `.Result` if you're in a non-async method

Comment: This should be the right answer, as it applies to a range of scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

> Unfortunately, the call never returns and the query hangs indefinitely...

You have a classic deadlock. That's why [*you shouldn't block on async code*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Behind the scenes, the compiler generates a state-machine and captures something called a `SynchronizationContext`. When you synchronously block the calling thread, the attempt to post the continuation back onto that same context causes the deadlock.

Instead of synchronously blocking with `.Result`, make your controller async and await on the `Task` returned from `GetSecret`:

```
public async IHttpActionResult FooAsync()
{
    var secret = await KeyVaultAccessor.GetSecretAsync("https://superSecretUri");
    return Ok();
}
```

*Side note* - Async methods should follow naming conventions and be postfixed with `Async`.

Answer (score -2):

Use the rest api...

```
public class AzureKeyVaultClient
{


    public string GetSecret(string name, string vault)
    {
        var client = new RestClient($"https://{vault}.vault.azure.net/");
        client.Authenticator = new AzureAuthenticator($"https://vault.azure.net");
        var request = new RestRequest($"secrets/{name}?api-version=2016-10-01");

        request.Method = Method.GET;


        var result = client.Execute(request);

        if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation($"Unable to retrieve {name} from {vault} with response {result.Content}");
            var exception =  GetKeyVaultErrorFromResponse(result.Content);
            throw exception;

        }
        else
        {
            return GetValueFromResponse(result.Content);
        }




    }

    public string GetValueFromResponse(string content)
    {

            var result = content.FromJson<keyvaultresponse>();
            return result.value;

    }


    public Exception GetKeyVaultErrorFromResponse(string content)
    {
        try
        {

            var result = content.FromJson<keyvautlerrorresponse>();
            var exception = new Exception($"{result.error.code} {result.error.message}");
            if(result.error.innererror!=null)
            {
                var innerException = new Exception($"{result.error.innererror.code} {result.error.innererror.message}");
            }

            return exception;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return e;
        }
    }

    class keyvaultresponse
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string contentType { get; set; }

    }

    class keyvautlerrorresponse
    {
        public keyvaulterror error {get;set;}
    }

    class keyvaulterror
    {
        public string code { get; set; }

        public string message { get; set; }

        public keyvaulterror innererror { get; set; }
    }

    class AzureAuthenticator : IAuthenticator
    {

        private string _authority;
        private string _clientId;
        private string _clientSecret;
        private string _resource;



        public AzureAuthenticator(string resource)
        {
            _authority = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:Authority"];
            _clientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:ClientId"];
            _clientSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:ClientSecret"];
            _resource = resource;

        }

        public AzureAuthenticator(string resource, string tennant, string clientid, string secret)
        {
            //https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tennant>/oauth2/oken
            _authority = authority;
            //azure client id (web app or native app
            _clientId = clientid;
            //azure client secret
            _clientSecret = secret;
            //vault.azure.net
            _resource = resource;

        }


        public void Authenticate(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request)
        {

            var token = GetS2SAccessTokenForProdMSA().AccessToken;
            //Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("obtained bearer token {0} from ADAL and adding to rest request",token));
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", token));


        }

        public AuthenticationResult GetS2SAccessTokenForProdMSA()
        {
            return GetS2SAccessToken(_authority, _resource, _clientId, _clientSecret);
        }

        private AuthenticationResult GetS2SAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
            AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = context.AcquireToken(
                resource,
                clientCredential);
            return authenticationResult;
        }

    }
}
```