# KeyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(url) causing delay

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-api-apps

We are using Azure KeyVault to store certain back end credentials that our Azure API uses to query. The GetSecretAsync call always takes at least 15 seconds to return. Is there any way to speed up this call. Below is the code used.

```
KeyVaultClient kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(TokenBasedAccessHelper.GetToken));    
var secret = Task.Run(async () => await kvClient.GetSecretAsync(url)).Result;
return secret.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see here: [KeyVault GetSecretAsync never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134579/keyvault-getsecretasync-never-returns)

Do not use async / result to get keyvault, there are deadlock situations that result.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.Please take a look at look this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134579/keyvault-getsecretasync-never-returns