# KeyVault getSecret() takes 13 seconds in Azure Functions nodejs runtime

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am experiencing a 13 seconds delay when getting a secret from the key vault. I have a Consumption Plan for the functions.

The RBAC permissions the Azure Functions *System Identity* has on the Key Vault service are:

[image: RBAC permissions]

I have created a singleton pattern for the KeyVault to improve performance but the first call always takes too long. This is how I access the secret:

```
const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
client = new SecretClient(process.env.KeyVault, credential);
var secretValue = (await client.getSecret("SecretName")).value;
```

I have never experienced this type of delay in .NET (hence my doubt on the actual library). I have searched on the internet about known issues like [this one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/23017) for Nodejs but my package version is higher so it should have been resolved. This is my package.json:

```
"@azure/identity": "^3.1.3"
"@azure/keyvault-secrets": "^4.7.0"
```

Other issues [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62190012/keyvaultclient-getsecretasyncurl-causing-delay) spoke about not using .Result to access the value but again, this is not my case. Any help and insight would be highly appreciated!

UPDATE:
The latency does not happen locally.

The latency in Azure is 33ms:

[image]

UPDATE AGAIN:
I created a function in dotnet to exlude that this is a nodejs library issue. The delay happens there as well.
[image]
Its only calling this secret:
[image]

Comment: Check the Azure Monitor logs, to which both the Identity and Key Vault packages log. It's possible there's a progressive retry delay because of an unexpected error response. Apart from the delay, is everything else working correct?

Comment: @Heath Yes after 15 sec I obtain the secret. However, this is causing a delay for my iOS app and I cannot pass the App Store review due to it. I created an Azure function instance for dotnet runtime and called the same key vault. It causes a delay also there. Whichever checks it is performing, 15sec is too much. See the UPDATE on the post for images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing from Consumption to a Dedicated plan where the app service doesn't shut down.
In this way, I can run another function which once a day checks the secrets and updates process.env variables. With a dedicated plan theoretically, the update of env variables should be done once on app service startup.
This way the long call will be done only once and the app will continue to use the env variables. Instead of a function, the initialization of process.env could be done on a startup class in case of a non-function backend.